# If $G$ is a finite group, then every element in the group has a finite order which is at most equal to $|G|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

If $G$ is a finite group, then show that every element in the group has a finite order which is at most equal to $|G|$.

My attempt:
Let $|G|=m$
and let $a\in{G}$ so $\text{Order}(a)=\min\{n\in{N}\mid a^n=e\}$.
Now let's consider the set $S=\{a^0,a^1,a^2...a^{|G|}\}$
and since $S$ contains $m+1$ elements that all $\in{G}$ (by law of composition $a*a$) so there must be two elements which are equal i.e $a^k=a^l$.
Hence all elements in $G$ have finite order at most equal to $m$.

Is this a valid proof?
Thanks

Comment: You've proven that $a^k = a^l$ for distinct $k$ and $l$, but you still need to show that $a^n = e$ for some $n$. Can you find $n$ from $k$ and $l$?

Answer (score 3):

Your definition of order of an element doesn't even make sense. The order of $a$ is the smallest $k$ such that $a^k=e$. And, since you used a definition which doesn't make sense, your proof doesn't make sense.

---

After the edition, the proof is still not valid because you were supposed to prove that $a^k=e$ for some natural $k$, but you didn't.

Comment: edited definition, my bad. Didn't really use it in proof just stated it...

Comment: hmm, is it to do with something as follows: suppose a$\in{G}$ and has order n, so n can be written as n=mq+r  for m,r$\in{z}$ , 0<r<m and |G|=m, $a^{mq+r}=a^r$

Comment: @Rivaldo No, you can use the division algorithm to prove that the order of an element divides the order of the finite group.  Your stated problem is to show that in a finite group, each element has finite order.  What you wrote (in the edited version) is almost correct; the idea (pigeonhole principle) is correct. You only need to say that you can choose $0 \leq l < k \leq |G|$ such that $a^l = a^k$.  Then multiply so that $a^m = e$ for some $m > 0$.  What should $m$ be?

Comment: @RobertBell m=k-l? thanks for help

Comment: Yes, that's correct! You're welcome.